# httpPost not working android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post, android-internet

I'm trying to send a httpPOST request to some url.This is my code.
I'm using ASync Task method which i found on the net

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new MyHttpPost().execute();

}
private class MyHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {


        @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://someurl");

            try {
             // Add your data
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("User", "abcd"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "1234"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "abcd"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "1234"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
           result = httpEntity.getContent();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            return true;
    }

    }



 }
```

I have also declared the network permissions in manifest

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
```

Yet after executing the application my server database isin't showing any hits.
Even if i comment out the list where i'm adding my data , Even for a blank httpPost   ,  there are no hits at all.
Please Help.Urgent.All answers appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: what is the response message? what you get from server?

Comment: In your code you replaced "http://someurl" by your own url right ?

Comment: ya.I've used a proper php script url. @Damien R.
Please have a look.I've edited the question again with theresponses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create DefaultHTTPClient with standart parameters.

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,
        HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

It's works fine for me.

Also I sets the request entity with UTF-8 encoding:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
```

Comment: httppost.setEntity can't resolve 

what library you are using. can you share it

Answer (score 0):

All these above code works but we need to implement a dependency for HttpPost and further to communicate with other server such as oracle etc..
Dependency file is :

***compile group: 'cz.msebera.android' , name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'***

after this issue will solve